# QGIS 2.01 Fedora 19 vs Windows SQL-Server Access

Tags: qgis, sql-server, windows, linux, qgis-2

i just installed QGIS 2.01 on Ubuntu / Fedora 19 / windows 8, configured ODBC-support for Fedora 19 and created ODBC-DSNs on the windows machine and the Fedora machine to the same SQL-Server 2012 instance where i stored some layers.

When i load these layers in the windows version of QGIS 2.01 everything works as expected, but in Fedora i get a strange behavior:

My point-Layers are loaded and displayed but every polygon layer i open, i get nothing or just the smallest polygons in that layer. No error message at all.

The connection works perfectly with iODBC, unixodbc and freetds.

Since only some small polygons appear: Is this some kind of resource problem?